# Webpack 3 minify css

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I am using webpack 3 and I have the following Webpack config file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./src/index.tsx", "./src/assets/css/styles.css"
    ],

    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    // devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename:  (getPath) => {
              return getPath('assets/css/styles.css').replace('css/js', 'css');
            },
            allChunks: true
          })
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: ["awesome-typescript-loader"] },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, enforce: "pre", use: "source-map-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                  fallback: 'style-loader',
                  use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            // If you are having trouble with urls not resolving add this setting.
                            // See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#url
                            url: false,
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                  ]
                })
              }
        ],

        loaders: [ {
            test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            loaders: [
                'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
            ]
        } ]
    }
};
```

I can see the css file generated into build folder, but it is not minified at all, I would like it to be as in one line all the css so it will be optimized, minified.

I dont know if I am using the right plugin in this case for this to happen.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Check if you have a PostCSS config file somewhere in your tree. Your webpack config seems good enough but it's hard to tell without looking at your source. OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin delegates to cssnano which then uses PostCSS to do the heavylifting.

Comment: @Mrchief I dont see any PostCSS config file on my tree, can you please give an example or can I modify current code to incdude postCss config?

Comment: I'd suggest to upload a sample reproducible repo or create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io)